# log the javascript functions called on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

Good day all.
I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to know which are the javascript functions called on a webpage. I'm not sure if it could be saied also "all function called under `document`, or `window`".
what I'm try to achieve is having some informations about some possible js injection into a webpage, so Ideally, I would like to have a javascript that monitor and log every function call on a page (client side).

I know this isn't a good CM for injection, I know my javascript, if present, could be broken by who inject the fraud js, but actually I'm in a stage of gathering informations, I'm simply try to think it in different ways.

Comment: [This sounds like what you are asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853256/how-to-get-javascript-function-calls-trace-at-runtime)

Comment: mmmmh, looks nice, thanks, I'll take a look